# "packages have unmet dependencies" while installing Code::Blocks

Tags: package-management, software-installation, 13.10, dependencies, code-blocks

While trying to install [Code::Blocks](https://www.codeblocks.org/), I run `sudo apt-get install libwxgtk2.8-dev`, but then receive an error listing many "unmet dependencies" for several packages.

The full list of errors:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 codeblocks:i386 : Depends: libatk1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.12.4) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libcairo2:i386 (>= 1.2.4) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libfontconfig1:i386 (>= 2.9.0) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libfreetype6:i386 (>= 2.2.1) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.22.0) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libglib2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.12.0) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libgtk2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libpango1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.14.0) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.6) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libwxbase2.8-0:i386 (>= 2.8.12.1) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libwxgtk2.8-0:i386 (>= 2.8.12.1) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: codeblocks-common:i386 (= 13.12-1) but it is not installable
                   Recommends: gcc:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                               g++:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: gdb:i386 but it is not going to be installed
 codeblocks-contrib:i386 : Depends: libatk1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.12.4) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: libbz2-1.0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: libcairo2:i386 (>= 1.2.4) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: libfontconfig1:i386 (>= 2.9.0) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: libfreetype6:i386 (>= 2.2.1) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: libgamin0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.22.0) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: libglib2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.12.0) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: libgtk2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: libhunspell-1.3-0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: libpango1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.14.0) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.6) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: libwxbase2.8-0:i386 (>= 2.8.12.1) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: libwxgtk2.8-0:i386 (>= 2.8.12.1) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: libx11-6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: zlib1g:i386 (>= 1:1.2.3.3) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: codeblocks-contrib-common:i386 (= 13.12-1) but it is not installable
                           Recommends: valgrind:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                           Recommends: cppcheck:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                           Recommends: cscope:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                           Recommends: cccc:i386 but it is not going to be installed
 codeblocks-dev:i386 : Depends: codeblocks-headers:i386 (= 13.12-1) but it is not installable
 codeblocks-headers : Depends: codeblocks-dev (>= 13.12-1) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: codeblocks-dev (< 13.12-1.1~) but it is not going to be installed
 codeblocks-libwxcontrib0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.3.6-6~) but it is not going to be installed
                                 Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
                                 Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
                                 Depends: libwxbase2.8-0:i386 (>= 2.8.12.1) but it is not going to be installed
                                 Depends: libwxgtk2.8-0:i386 (>= 2.8.12.1) but it is not going to be installed
                                 Depends: binutils:i386 (>= 2.14.90.0.7) but it is not going to be installed
 codeblocks-wxcontrib-headers : Depends: codeblocks-wxcontrib-dev (>= 13.12-1) but it is not installable
                                Depends: codeblocks-wxcontrib-dev (< 13.12-1.1~) but it is not installable
 libcodeblocks0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.11) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.6) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libwxbase2.8-0:i386 (>= 2.8.12.1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libwxgtk2.8-0:i386 (>= 2.8.12.1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: binutils:i386 (>= 2.14.90.0.7) but it is not going to be installed
 libwxgtk2.8-dev : Depends: wx-common but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: wx2.8-headers (= 2.8.12.1-14ubuntu1.1) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libwxgtk2.8-0 (= 2.8.12.1-14ubuntu1.1) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libwxbase2.8-dev (= 2.8.12.1-14ubuntu1.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libwxsmithlib0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libwxbase2.8-0:i386 (>= 2.8.12.1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libwxgtk2.8-0:i386 (>= 2.8.12.1) but it is not going to be installed
 wxsmith-headers : Depends: wxsmith-dev (>= 13.12-1) but it is not installable
                   Depends: wxsmith-dev (< 13.12-1.1~) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I get these errors for every single package and it happens after I try to get build essentials.

EDIT: After continuing to toil, there are still 2 dependencies that nothing can fix.

- libgcc1 (>=1:4.1.1) but 1:4.8.1-10ubuntu9 is to be installed
- codeblocks-common(=12.11-3) but 13.12-1 is to be installed

I tried re-installing. Auto remove didn't work.

EDIT: I tried `-f install` again to post my results. Here is what I get:

```
somepackages 
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 240 not upgraded.
```

I still can't install the final two dependencies for Code::Blocks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [**How do I resolve unmet dependencies?**](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies). As in your end results explains that you've unmet dependencies and to try `sudo apt-get -f install`. Try it first & Also refer the link specified in this comment.

Comment: i did it gaves same thing!  also i can't go software center! sorry but it was a long error couldn't seach net for!

Comment: Open a terminal with `CTRL+ALT+T` & type `sudo apt-get -f install`. If you get any error, please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/413535/edit) your question and post the output separate. :)

Answer (score 3):

Have you actually tried running: `sudo apt-get -f install`? That should fix current installed packages by installing unmet dependencies.

Comment: restarting worked! need 30mb of downloads :( no other choice! downloading and will see what happened! my net is data limited ! and its so expensive! EDIT: worked ! thanks so much!! sorry for this please don't give me ban or something it wont happen again! it was mostly because it was long error and i didn't know what to search for!

Comment: theres still 2 other dependies that nothing can fix !
 libgcc1 (>=1:4.1.1) but 1:4.8.1-10ubuntu9 is to be isntalled 
codeblocks-common(=12.11-3) but 13.12-1 is to be isntalled

Comment: Try installing those two manually, maybe there are security updates that won't allow you to install an older version.